# Detect peer port number, knowing only the IP address

Tags: sockets, networking, peer

I want to have 2 applications that communicate over internet, socket base. Each is a server and a client. Each applications will only know the IP address of the other peer, but not the port number. Port number is random, whatever is free on the system when the application starts.

Idea would be one application sends some kind of discovery message containing its own port number as payload data. The other receives the message and starts communication using the received port number.

Could someone recommend how to send this "discovery message" to detect the port number used by the other peer, without using a server to exchange the information?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just do things the normal, old fashioned way and having a server listen at a known port?

Comment: sounds like TFTP, but the initial pkt is raw instead of UDP/69. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_File_Transfer_Protocol